# windows system call

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, system-calls

On Linux it seems `getpid()` is the simplest system call to invoke to best-measure the time taken for a system call. Would somebody be able to refer me to a simple windows system call I could make to measure the time spent changing to kernel mode and back please?

I did google and found a list of Windows System calls on MSDN website, but they all referred to opening files- which seemed strange:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0wd4t32.aspx

I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: sorry, how does `getpid()` give you any timing related data?

Comment: I use time(0), which seems a little simpler.  On my 7 yr old Dell, Linux 12.04 achieves 13.2 mega time(0)'s per second, but only 12.3 mega getpid()'s per second.  Sorry, not a Win 7 answer.

Comment: If you can manage to call it from user-mode, I think `PsGetProcessExitTime` is the simplest function I can find.

Comment: @RedAlert "the simplest system call to invoke to best-measure the time taken for a system call"

Comment: @Mehrdad have included <windows.h> but cannot see to access that function.

Comment: @user3811839: Yeah I don't think there is a syscall for it, it's just the simplest kernel-mode function I could find.

Comment: @user3811839: You might need to choose a "slow" syscall, but give it invalid parameters so that it fails fast.

Comment: That link is documentation for the C runtime, not for the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (and this is just based on intuition) is to try something like

```
CloseHandle(NULL)
```

or

```
WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(0, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE)
```

on the grounds that it *should* be a no-op. However, I don't have any evidence to support this.

---

#### Update

A little benchmarking on Win8.1 x64 shows the (undocumented) `NtDisplayString(NULL)` function is even faster, followed by the semi-documented `NtAllocateLocallyUniqueId(&some_luid)`. You'll have to dynamically load them from NTDLL using `GetProcAddress`; the signatures are:

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI PNtAllocateLocallyUniqueId(PLUID LUID);
NTSTATUS NTAPI PNtDisplayString(PUNICODE_STRING DisplayString);
```

Comment: GetStartupInfo would be another reasonable guess, or RevertToSelf when no impersonation is in place (or perhaps even when it is).  For any of these, you'll need some way to check whether a kernel-mode transition actually took place; the Windows API optimizes these away where possible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I don't see why `GetStartupInfo` would need a kernel-mode transition.

Comment: You're quite right, that information is probably copied into user-space during process creation.  But you never know. :-)